# How is the zoom tooltip in the "Coordinates Tool" implemented?

Tags: performance-tuning, gui-construction, implementation-details, interface, coordinate

I notice that the built-in "Coordinates Tool" has a very efficient zoom tooltip displaying an enlarged portion of the image along with coordinates and row/column indices:

[image: screenshot]

How to get the source code of this tool? Or **how can we implement such an efficient tooltip ourselves** (I want to replicate all the tooltip functionality)?

Comment: **How to get the source code of this tool?** get a job at WRI and then you can look at all the source code :)   sorry, could not help it.  I wonder if it is using Dynamics somehow?

Comment: @Nasser Often there is an undocumented way to get the source. For example, via `FrontEndResource` or some other trick. So I don't consider the question unanswerable.

Comment: It looks like the tool is implemented entirely in the frontend: If you have an image selected while evaluating ``FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`Select2DTool["GetPixelPointMarkers"]]``, you will get the tooltip. However, the "select 2D tool" name somehow implies that the frontend knows how to select the tool, with no kernel involvement (you can also see by looking at the CPU usage of the various threads that the kernel doesn't seem to do much, if anything). The string `"GetPixelPointMarkers"` also only appears a single time in the entire installation directory

Comment: @LukasLang This can be seen as a solution (although I would like to draw rectangles on the image instead of markers). But how can I programmatically get the row/column indices for the markers without envoking the "Coordinates Tool"? For example, print a table with them.

Comment: @LukasLang I just found that ``FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`Select2DTool["GetRectangleImageSelection"]]`` allows to draw a rectangle selection with the tooltip as I wish. But I still can't figure out how to get the row/column indices for the selection.

Comment: @LukasLang The tooltip itself, without the drawing functionality, can be invoked with ``FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`Select2DTool["DisplayImageTooltip"]]``.

Comment: Looking at the code of the image toolbar, I would have guessed that ``MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`Value[FEPrivate`GetImagePixelPointMarkersList[]]]`` gives you the list of selected points (the one that is also shown in the table in the toolbar). However, it seems to always return `$Failed` for me

Comment: @LukasLang How do you get the code of the image toolbar?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It's in `FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "SystemResources", "AttedImage2D.nb"}`

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks. The list of indices can be obtained with ``MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
 FrontEnd`Value[FEPrivate`GetlImageMarkersIndicesList[NotebookSelection[]]]]``.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a proof-of-concept demonstration of how to build your own tooltip with reasonable performance:

```
tooltip[img_] :=
 EventHandler[
  MouseAppearance[
   img,
   Dynamic@Graphics[
     {
      Red,
      Line@{{{0.05, 0.9}, {0.05, 1}}, {{0, 0.95}, {0.1, 0.95}}},
      Inset[
       Graphics[
        {
         Inset[img,
          {1, 1},
          {
           FEPrivate`Ceiling@FEPrivate`Part[FrontEnd`MousePosition["Graphics"], 1],
           FEPrivate`Ceiling@FEPrivate`Part[FrontEnd`MousePosition["Graphics"], 2]
           },
          ImageDimensions@img
          ],
         EdgeForm@Red,
         FaceForm@None,
         Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]
         },
        PlotRange -> {{-4, 5}, {-4, 5}},
        Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, FrameStyle -> Thick,
        PlotRangeClipping -> True
        ],
       {0.1, 0.9},
       Scaled@{0, 1},
       Scaled@{0.9, 0.9}
       ]
      },
     ImageSize -> 125,
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}
     ],
   {0.05, 0.95}
   ],
  {
   "MouseClicked" :> Print@MousePosition@"Graphics"
   }
  ]

tooltip@ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}]
```

[image]

Notes:

- The tooltip is shown by setting the mouse appearance via `MouseAppearance`. This allows the tooltip to smoothly follow the cursor position. The red cross is aligned such that the alignment point of the cursor (set to `{0.05,0.95}`) is at its center
- The zoomed image displayed is achieved by a series of nested `Inset`s. This allows us to crop the image and move it around without actually doing any image processing, we are simply changing the shown portion of the image.
- The part with `` FEPrivate`Ceiling@... `` is effectively computing the inset position in the front end, and rounding it to the appropriate pixel value (to get the pixel snapping behavior).
- The coordinates of the innermost image graphics are both set to reflect the `ImageDimensions`, so 1 unit is 1 pixel. This makes many things a lot easier, especially the control of how many pixels are shown: This is essentially driven by the `PlotRange->{{-4,5},{-4,5}}` setting.

Comment: Great! One problem: when I add `"MouseClicked":>Print[MousePosition["Graphics"]]`, it prints the coordinates, but the tooltip disappears. How can it be avoided?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Please see the update - I just realized that you can set the cursor via `MouseAppearance` in this case, which makes everything more robust, and it also fixes the issue you mentioned

Comment: Another problem: if the image contains the `ImageResolution` option, the tooltip breaks. Even with `ImageResolution -> Automatic`, the tooltip is blurred. Addition of `BaseStyle->{Antialiasing->False}` doesn't help.

Comment: As a workaround setting `ImageResolution->72` works.

Comment: It is always a nice surprise to see new ways to create robust and performant applets in Mathematica.  But I really did wish all these features were better documented and explained.

Comment: By the way, why did you place the main image within `Inset` rather than just putting it top level?

Comment: @QuantumDot I wanted to make sure that `MousePosition["Graphics"]` gave values in pixels, and it honestly didn't occur to me to check whether a raw image already did that. But thanks for the input, I have now simplified the answer

Answer (score 10):

Answering the first part of my question (thanks to [Lukas Lang](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36508/lukas-lang) for pointing me in the right direction!).

The source code for the [Image Assistant Toolbar](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/GetCoordinatesFromAnImage.html) that appears when you select `Image` in the FrontEnd is in the file

```
FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "SystemResources", 
  "AttachedImage2D.nb"}
```

In particular, the zooming tooltip can be invoked by evaluating

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`Select2DTool["DisplayImageTooltip"]]
```

when an `Image` is selected. It appears to be implemented at a low level in the FrontEnd, so the source code is not available.

The option `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "DisplayImagePixels"]` determines whether to show the zoomed portion of the image in the tooltip. The default value for this option is `Automatic`, what is equivalent to `"ExploreView"`. With the value `"TooltipInfo"` the tooltip will be shown without the zoomed image. For displaying the zoomed image, we need to set `"DetailExploreView"`:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "DisplayImagePixels"] = "DetailExploreView";
SelectionMove[PreviousCell[], All, CellContents]
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`Select2DTool["DisplayImageTooltip"]]
```

[image: screenshot]

The pixel size of the zoomed image can be controlled via `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "RasterExploreViewRange"]`.

Evaluating

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`Select2DTool["GetPixelPointMarkers"]]
```

activates also the point marker creation functionality. After creating the markers, the list of their row/column indices can be obtained with

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`Value[FEPrivate`GetlImageMarkersIndicesList[NotebookSelection[]]]]
```

The makers can be removed with

```
FrontEndTokenExecute["ClearPixelPointMarkers"]
```

---

With the above, we can develop the following simple pixel picker interface:

```
PixelPickerInterface[i_Image] := 
  With[{id = CreateUUID[], id2 = CreateUUID[], 
    is = {{1, #}, {1, #}} &[101./CurrentValue["WindowResolution"]*72]},
   With[{init := (CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "DisplayImagePixels"] = "DetailExploreView";
       SelectionMove[First@Cells[CellTags -> id], All, CellContents, 
        AutoScroll -> False];
       SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, Graphics, AutoScroll -> False];
       SetOptions[
        First@Cells[NotebookSelection[], CellTags -> "AttachedImage2D", 
          AttachedCell -> True], CellSize -> {0, 0}];
       FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`Select2DTool["GetPixelPointMarkers"]])},
    CellPrint[
     ExpressionCell[i, "Output", CellTags -> id, CellFrameLabels -> {{None, None}, {None,
         ToBoxes@Pane[Row[{Spacer[40],
             Button["Start Image Assistant Interface", init],
             Button["Print Markers Indices",
              NotebookDelete[Cells[CellTags -> id2]]; init;
              With[{inds = 
                 MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
                  FrontEnd`Value[
                   FEPrivate`GetlImageMarkersIndicesList[NotebookSelection[]]]]},
               CellPrint@Table[
                 ExpressionCell[
                  Row[Prepend[
                    Table[Image[
                    ImageTake[i, {-sh, sh} + ind[[1, 1]], {-sh, sh} + ind[[2, 2]]], 
                    ImageSize -> is], {sh, {0, 1, 4, 10, 50}}], 
                    Labeled[{ind[[1, 1]], ind[[2, 2]]}, "row,col"]], "->"], "Echo", 
                  CellTags -> id2], {ind, inds}]]],
             Button["Clear Markers",
              init; FrontEndTokenExecute["ClearPixelPointMarkers"]],
             Slider[Dynamic[CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "RasterExploreViewRange"]], {39, 
               3, -1}, ImageSize -> Small],
             Dynamic[CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "RasterExploreViewRange"]]
             }], Full, Alignment -> Left]}}]]
    ]];


PixelPickerInterface[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}]]
```

[image: screesnhot]