# How to control the Image Assistant Toolbar?

Tags: front-end, image, customization, system-performance

<sup>(Cross-posted on the [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2618380).)</sup>

When we select an `Image` in the FrontEnd, the [Image Assistant Toolbar](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/GetCoordinatesFromAnImage.html) appears attached under it:

[image: toolbar]

How can we temporarily prevent the toolbar from appearing when an `Image` is selected?

Answer (score 3):

Searching through the options we find `ImageEditMode`, which appears to do the trick:

```
Checkbox@Dynamic@enabled
Style[RandomImage[], RasterBoxOptions -> {ImageEditMode -> Dynamic@enabled}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately this disables the [zooming tooltip](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/273580/280) functionality that I want to keep working... :( My goal is to disable only the toolbar, not the tooltip functionality.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit in my answer... I noticed that too, that's why I made the example with a `Dynamic` option value. You can set the value to `True` before invoking the tooltip, and back to `False` when you are done. Would that solve your problems?

Comment: Not really. Because I'm assuming iterative creation of markers, and therefore it would be convenient to have the tooltip functionality available throughout the session. The toolbar simply takes up too much screen space and gets in the way.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be the following stylesheet-based approach:

```
(* add this to the Stylesheet of the notebook / the StyleDefinitions option *)
Cell[StyleData["AttachedCell"],
  CellSize->Dynamic@If[
    Not[CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession,{TaggingRules,"ImageAssistantEnabled"}]] && 
     CurrentValue[CellTags]==="AttachedImage2D",
    {0,0},
    {Automatic,Automatic}
  ]
]

(* this goes into the notebook itself *)
Checkbox@Dynamic@CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, "ImageAssistantEnabled"}]
RandomImage[]

CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "DisplayImagePixels"] = "DetailExploreView";
SelectionMove[PreviousCell[], All, CellContents]
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`Select2DTool["GetPixelPointMarkers"]]
```

[image]

Notes:

- Effectively, this modifies the style of all attached cells (of which the toolbar is one) and sets their `CellSize` to `{0,0}` if we have an enable-flag set and the cell has the `"AttachedImage2D"` `CellTags` entry.
- This method shouldn't interfere with any related functionality, since the
  toolbar is still "there", just not visible to the user.
- The flag is set as a `$FrontEndSession` `TaggingRules` entry since I couldn't get global variables to work in my quick tests, and that seemed like the next best thing.
- As for the tag: I discovered that by looking at the code of the toolbar, and noting that the outermost cell had this tag as identifying information (I would have preferred a named style, but this is close enough):

  ```
  FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "SystemResources", "AttachedImage2D.nb"}
  ```

Comment: May be it is possible to use `CellDynamicExpression` for this instead of `StyleDefinitions`? Like this (but this naive implementation doesn't work):  `CellDynamicExpression -> 
 Dynamic[CurrentValue[
   First@Cells[EvaluationCell[], CellTags -> "AttachedImage2D", AttachedCell -> True], 
   CellSize], (# = {0, 0}) &]`?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov You'd probably need to force continuous updating using `UpdateInternal`, which seems like it could kill performance

Answer (score 1):

For now, I know only how to remove the toolbar programmatically:

```
NotebookDelete[Cells[CellTags -> "AttachedImage2D", AttachedCell -> True]]
```

But it appears again when I click on the image...